# CSS how to truncate text without ellipsis (in Safari)

Tags: css, safari

I know I can use

```
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
```

But I don't want to have ellipsis

I found that I can have string in `text-overflow` but it doesn't work in Safari.

I tried:

```
text-overflow: "";
```

It works in Firefox, but not in Safari

Anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because right now only Firefox supports this feature. See also:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_text-overflow_string

You can use `text-overflow: clip` to get rid of the ellipsis tough.

Comment: using text-overflow: clip will not hide the overflowed text, which means it may cause half of a character displaying in the edge of a div. what I want is a clear cut of text. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use some CSS to make text invisible and wrap the actual text in span that is opposite to it. For example, you can use color:

```css
.truncate-no-ellipsis {
  width: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.text {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="truncate-no-ellipsis">
<span class="text">This is a long truncated text</span>
</div>
```